# What is the best way to share elements of a react website with other sites

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a website written in React and I would like to share portions of that site with other websites in our domain.  I've explored using WebPack, linking the Git repos together, and a few other options.  What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking to share the React components, you can publish them as NPM components and then use them anywhere.

Comment: Would publishing them as a NPM component allow us to share UI elements in those components also?

Comment: Why does it matter if it's a UI element or not? NPM packages are just bundles of code that are meant to be shared and re-used between projects.